# Can my question be reopened?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

My question [Understanding Spliterator, Collector and Stream in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235606/new-java-8-features-undertanding-spliterator-collector-and-stream) was closed as too broad. I made some edits there trying to narrow the scope to let it be reopened and left a comment asking if it is ok now or if I still need to improve it somehow. However, it was still not reopened and nobody answered my comment.

So can it be reopened now? If not, what I still need to do to improve it?

Comment: It still seems way too broad to me.  You're basically asking for everything about two concepts.  That's not a very specific question at all.

Answer (score 10):

I'll address your actual questions:

> So, my actual questions are: What exactly is a Spliterator and a Collector and how can I use them? If I am willing to write my own Spliterator or Collector (and probably my own Stream in that process), what should I do and do not?

First, you have 2.5 (one kind of goes with another) questions there. It would be better to post *multiple questions* than to post one question with three questions in it. But wait! Let's look at the questions one by one

> What exactly is a Spliterator and a Collector and how can I use them?

This in and of itself would be too broad - it seems like it would be better application of a manual or a blog post somewhere. You're asking what something is and how to use it. It would be like if I asked *what are two-by-fours and how do I use them* on DIY. Go Google it.

> If I am willing to write my own Spliterator or Collector (and probably my own Stream in that process), what should I do and do not?

Here you have the same problem: Too broad. The best way I can address this is to again look to a DIY example: *If I was to build my own house (and probably my own driveway in the process), what should I do and not do?*

When you combine the two, you get a too-broad question. Plain and simple.

Comment: This is because the purpose of these interfaces were so obscure for me that I even could not get what they were supposed to do, so I came here to ask for help. And yes, I've read some examples, read the documentation and even looked at the source code, but still did not understand. Since the question was posted a few days ago, I managed to understand the Collector with some hours of trial and error, though I'm still not confortable with it. About the Spliterator, still didn't unerstand how they should work, even with it's source code full of javadocs in my monitor at this exact moment.